# Como deixar seta de navegação centralizada em flexslider

Tags: css

Tenho um banner que é exibido em um flexslider e preciso deixar as setas de navegação centralizadas nas laterais, hoje estão na base. Por mais que altere não consigo deixa-las centralizada, meus limitados conhecimentos em css me limitam.

A página pode ser vista aqui: [Flexslider](http://moveissaobento.com.br/msb/)

O css está assim:

```
.flex-direction-nav a {
    display: block;
    width: 27px;
    height: 27px;
    background-image: url(../images/slider/arrows.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-indent: -999em;
}
.flex-direction-nav a.flex-prev, .flex-direction-nav a.flex-prev.flex-disabled {
    background-position: 10px 7px;
}
.flex-direction-nav a.flex-next, .flex-direction-nav a.flex-next.flex-disabled {
    background-position: -17px 7px;
}
.flex-direction-nav a.flex-disabled:link, .flex-direction-nav a.flex-disabled:visited, .flex-direction-nav a.flex-disabled:hover, .flex-direction-nav a.flex-disabled:active {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
    cursor: default;
}
/* Control Nav */

.flex-control-nav {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 70px;
    bottom: 15px;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
    padding: 10px 20px;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 50;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se mudares o `bottom` de `15px` para `150px` consegues o efeito desejado:

```
.flex-direction-nav {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 150px; <---------------------AQUI
```

Comment: Olá @JorgeB., fiz a alteração mas continua do mesmo modo, ainda na base o que mudou foram os marcadores, o quadradinhos que mostram a quantidade de imagens.

Comment: Olá, agora consegui, seguindo a dica alterei o local correto.

Comment: Ainda bem que pude ajudar :)